# MySQL using different index depending on limit value with ORDER BY query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

This is weird to me:
One table 'ACTIVITIES' with one index on ACTIVITY_DATE. The exact same query with different LIMIT value results in different execution plan.

Here it is:

```
mysql> explain select * from ACTIVITIES order by ACTIVITY_DATE desc limit 20
    -> ;
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ACTIVITIES | index | NULL          | ACTI_DATE_I | 4       | NULL |   20 |       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select * from ACTIVITIES order by ACTIVITY_DATE desc limit 150
    -> ;
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra          |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ACTIVITIES | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 10629 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How come when I limit 150 it is not using the index? I mean, scanning 150 lines seems faster than scanning 10629 rows, right?

**EDIT**

The query uses the index till "limit 96" and starts filesort at "limit 97".
The table has nothing specific, even not a foreign key, here is the complete create table:

```
mysql> show create table ACTIVITIES\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: ACTIVITIES
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `ACTIVITIES` (
  `ACTIVITY_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ACTIVITY_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `USER_KEY` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ITEM_KEY` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ACTIVITY_TYPE` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `EXTRA` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IS_VISIBLE` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ACTIVITY_ID`),
  KEY `ACTI_USER_I` (`USER_KEY`,`ACTIVITY_DATE`),
  KEY `ACTIVITY_ITEM_I` (`ITEM_KEY`,`ACTIVITY_DATE`),
  KEY `ACTI_ITEM_TYPE_I` (`ITEM_KEY`,`ACTIVITY_TYPE`,`ACTIVITY_DATE`),
  KEY `ACTI_DATE_I` (`ACTIVITY_DATE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10091 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Logs    activity'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I also tried to run "ANALYSE TABLE ACTIVITIES" but that did not change a thing.

Comment: That's very strange you are right though. Can you show the `CREATE` please? Also at what limit does filesort start?

Answer (score 0):

That's the way things go.  Bear with me a minute...

The Optimizer would like to use an INDEX, in this case ACTI_DATE_I.  But it does not want to use it if that would be slower.

Plan A:  Use the index.

1. Reach into the BTree-structured index at the end (because of DESC)
2. Scan backward
3. For each row in the index, look up the corresponding row in the data.  Note:  The index has (ACTIVITY_DATE, ACTIVITY_ID) because the PRIMARY KEY is implicitly appended to any secondary key.  To reach into the "data" using the PK (ACTIVITY_ID) is another BTree lookup, potentially random.  Hence, it is potentially slow.  (But not very slow in your case.)
4. This stops after LIMIT rows.

Plan B:  Ignore the table

1. Scan the table, building a tmp table.  (Likely to be in-memory.)
2. Sort the tmp table
3. Peel off LIMIT rows.

In your case (96 -- 1% of 10K) it is surprising that it picked the table scan.  Normally, the cutoff is somewhere around 10%-30% of the number of rows in the table.

`ANALYZE TABLE` *should* have caused a recalculation of the statistics, which *could* have convinced it to go with the other Plan.

What version of MySQL are you using?  (No, I don't know of any changes in this area.)

One thing you could try:  `OPTIMIZE TABLE ACTIVITIES;`  That will rebuild the table, thereby repacking the blocks and leading to *potentially* different statistics.  If that helps, I would like to know it -- since I normally say "Optimize table is useless".

Comment: Reproduced this use-case on 5.1.41 (local), my server is in 5.5.38 (Google cloud-sql), and also reproduced on 5.6.23 (some slave db). Exact same result after OPTIMIZE. I tried to make some tests, same result with only one index, no PK. same limitation with 20K, but with 30K it chooses index till LIMIT 160. So I think you are right it is a percentage of rows...

Comment: I suspect it is some kind of "cost" model -- the percentage is simply a way for us mere mortals to deal with it.  ;)  Consider filing a bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com -- It sounds like a bug to me.  I don't spot anything strange about what you are doing that could justify what happened.

Comment: Yes, I do agree with you and think it's a bug as this is very unexpected behavior. I will file a bug and post back here as soon as I know more

Comment: Works OK with MyISAM though, so it is InnoDB related

Comment: Oracle would be eager to hear about it.  The statistics are generated by the Engine in question.  Please provide us with a link to the bug.