# MySQL Slow When Setting Limit To 13214

Tags: mysql

Can anyone explain the huge execution time between these two queries?

**Query #1:**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE MAX(id) as id 
FROM optin 
WHERE siteNum = 3895 
GROUP BY uid LIMIT 0,13213
```

**Execution time:** 0.092 seconds

*Explain Query#1 says* - **type=index, possible keys=siteNum, key = uid, rows =23700**

**Query #2:**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE MAX(id) as id 
FROM optin 
WHERE siteNum = 3895 
GROUP BY uid LIMIT 0,13214
```

**Execution time:** 13.757 seconds

*Explain Query#2 says* - **type=ref, possible keys=siteNum, key = siteNum, rows =637723**

The only difference is the LIMIT. Anything above 1323 is extremely slow.

What does that mean? Was there an problem while indexing?

[image: Proof/Screenshot]

Comment: can you provide a screenshot with proof please?

Comment: or, better yet, proper CREATE TABLE statements and the result of the EXPLAIN for both queries.

Comment: Interesting. Explains shed some insight. Added to original question.

Comment: this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125634/mysql-using-different-index-depending-on-limit-value-with-order-by-query

Comment: how much time does it take when you force "use index" ?

Comment: Adding "USE INDEX(uid)" drops the query time to 0.1 seconds - amazing. Problem is, for "sites" that have smaller uid count the USE INDEX(uid) then makes their query time 3-4 seconds longer than had it used the automated index (Site)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html

> If you select only a few rows with LIMIT, MySQL uses indexes in some
>   cases when normally it would prefer to do a full table scan.

So LIMIT changes how it uses indices. Including the indexing on the table might explain this better, but it appears the smaller `LIMIT` is using a `uid` from an index whereas the larger `LIMIT` is using a `ref` off `siteNum`.

For documentation on Explain:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html